# Как сменить версию php5.6 на php7 в настройках apache2.4?

Tags: php, apache, php7, apache2.4

Установил php7 из исходников [по этой рекомендации](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987883/how-do-i-install-php-7-php-next-generation-on-ubuntu). В консоли команда `php -v` выдает:

> PHP 7.1.0-dev (cli) (built: Jan  9 2016 21:22:15) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.1.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

но apache2.4 по-прежнему использует версию php5.6 Как заставить работать apache2.4 с установленным из исходников php7?

Comment: apache не использует интерпретатор php (по крайней мере, в традиционной схеме его применения). он использует библиотеку php, собранную именно как модуль для apache. вы её собрали?

Comment: У апача немного иная архитектура. Апач не использует какую-то конфигурируемую версию PHP, он использует скомплированный модуль (адаптер), поэтому вам нужен mod_php верной версии для апача.

Comment: команда make install не собирает модуль для apache?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

На самом деле, все оказалось просто:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0

sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql // установит модуль для работы с mysql
sudo apt-get install php7.0-pgsql // установит модуль для работы с postgresql
sudo apt-get install php-xdebug   // обратите внимание, некоторые пакеты для php7.0
                                  // могут не иметь суффикса в названии
```

Эти команды установят последнюю версию php7.0

Нужно отметить, что команды добавления/удаления модулей для php7.0 выглядят иначе-проще. Например, чтоб подключить модуль **xdebug** нужно выполнить `phpenmode xdebug`, конечно, его предварительно нужно установить.

Answer (score 0):

sudo update-alternatives --config php

Answer (score -2):

`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` – в этом файле указать используемую версию.